# Pine Script How do you create alert?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

if you have indicator with buy/sell signals, how would you create alert for it using 1 alert:

For example: the alert will be: if i get a buy signal, i get alert saying “buy” and ticker. And same for sell basically.

Its easy to create 2 alerts (1 for buy and 1 for sell), but how would you do it in 1 alert. Please share example code Thank You

This is what I had but it only gives me alert for buy/sell. it doesnt tell me what ticker it is:

if buy or sell

newalert = (buy ? "BUY" : sell ? "SELL" : na),

alert(newalert)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
study("My Script")
buy = bar_index % 2 == 0
sell = bar_index % 2 == 1
if buy
    alert("buy " + syminfo.ticker)
if sell
    alert("sell " + syminfo.ticker)
```

[image]